# Proving that in a complete graph $\kappa(K_{n}) = \delta(K_{n})$

Tags: graph-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing

Since $K_{n}$ is n-1 regular. Then $\delta(G)$ must be n-1. Since $\kappa(K_{n}) \leq \delta(K_{n})$ then by definition they must be equivalent.

Am I approaching this proof the right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not really a need to quote that inequality in this case: you can directly show that both values are $n-1$.

Certainly $\delta(K_n)$ is $n-1$ as you know, and now just apply the definition of $\kappa$ to see that $\kappa(K_n)=n-1$: Since $K_n$ contains at least (well, exactly) $(n-1)+1$ vertices and there is no set of $(n-1)-1$ vertices whose removal results in a disconnected graph, we have $\kappa(K_n)\geq n-1$. But we cannot replace $n-1$ by a larger value since $K_n$ has only $n$ vertices. Thus $\kappa(K_n)=n-1.$.