# Proving that in a complete graph $\lambda(K_{n}) = \delta(K_{n})$

Tags: graph-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing

Since $K_{n}$ is n-1 regular. Then $\lambda(G)$ must be n-1. Since $\lambda(K_{n}) \leq \delta(K_{n})$ then by definition they must be equivalent.

Can I use the definition or should I say since $K_{n}$ is n-1 regular it will take at least n-1 edges to disconnect the graph from other vertices? Do I have to mention anything why it wouldn't be n edges?

Comment: What is $\lambda$? Edge-connectivity?

Comment: Yes. Should I mention something about its minimum number of edges it must have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just apply your [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1289210/proving-that-in-a-complete-graph-kappak-n-deltak-n/1289282#1289282) to the inequality $\kappa(G)\leq \lambda(G)\leq \delta(G)$ which holds for any graph $G$.